# Shopping cart icon at the top header

Tags: shopping-cart

Im recently having problems with shopping cart icon. It works everywhere correctly and could be seen at the top at any device, however on android devices the cart icon just disappears (on landscape version It works although). Does anyone have any clue where should I start? I tried somehow through CSS. Funny It works even with iOS devices..

http://nordickliima.ee/

[Shopping cart is missing on android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8usKQ.png)

[Landscape version (Android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbdlD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your css add a `display: none` to the "wrap-cart-count" class for device with width under 360 pixels

```
@media (max-width: 360px)
#header .wrap-cart-count {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It wants me to add Lbrace at the second line. Aheader of the #header id.

Comment: I realised it works with 661x776px, under that it disappears.

Comment: You should try to remove the `display:none` line on your css. This line is also present in your "responsive.css" lib so the best thing to do is to overwrite it. For example try to replace `display:none` by `display: inline` in the code I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Still struggle with that issue. Changed display to inline from responsive.css. On some Android devices it works, but still got one device that doesn't show the icon. Tried to make logo smaller, but still the same. At 660x776 pixels it disappears.